# How to efficiently convert DataSet.Tables to List<DataTable>?

Tags: list, datatable, dataset, c#-3.0

I see many posts about converting the table(s) in a DataSet to a list of DataRows or other row data but I was unable to find anything about this question. This is what I came up with using .Net 3.0:

```
    public static List<DataTable> DataSetToList(DataSet ds)
    {
        List<DataTable> result = new List<DataTable>();

        foreach (DataTable dtbl in ds.Tables)
        {
            result.Add(dtbl);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is there a better way, excluding an extension method?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Based on [Why LINQ casting with a Data.DataTableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805690/why-linq-casting-with-a-data-datatablecollection) this will work;

```
List<DataTable> result = new List<DataTable>(ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer works in .Net 3.5 and above unless there is an include that I left out. I do have System.linq. I also found that in .Net 3.5 and up the following works: List<DataTable> list = ds.Tables.ToList();

Comment: @Soenhay what is your include? I couldn't seem to use `ToList()` for some reason. Had missed you looking for a .Net 3.0 option though.

Comment: I am sorry I was mistaken, I had this extension method in my project so it is not actually in .net:
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tables"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<DataTable> ToList(this DataTableCollection tables)
        {
            List<DataTable> result = new List<DataTable>();

            foreach (DataTable dtbl in tables)
            {
                result.Add(dtbl);
            }

            return result;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<DataTable> sequence = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

or

```
List<DataTable> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: What I mean is to convert a DataTableCollection into a List<DataTable>. 
dt.AsEnumerable().ToList(); returns List<DataRow>.