# Write A DataTable with variable columns into a database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, oledb

This could have been much easier if I used `SqlConnection`. But now I have an `OleDbConnection` and I would like to copy an entire `DataTable` into a database table. The `DataTable` can have different columns every time. So I would like only the matching columns to be inserted.

How can I achieve this without iterating through my `DataTable` columns all the time and building an INSERT query according to that?

Comment: having a structure that keep changing you wont be able to do it without some sort of iteration

Comment: @Franck true. but how can such thing exist with `SqlBulkCopy` but if I use `OleDb` I have to go through things brick by brick?

Comment: Why not change the connection and not use OleDB?

Comment: @SeanLange the connection string to the database has a `provider` value that is not supported by `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Well if you are connecting to sql server can you change the application so you have a connection string that doesn't force you to use an outdated technology. Or maybe add a second connection string to the config file?

Comment: @SeanLange I wouldn't call `OleDb` outdated necessarily. I am willing to provide support for other types of databases in the future. I would rather keep a generic solution. And adding a separate connection string and save it somewhere else for rainy days is not something I would like to have on my program.

Comment: OLEDB has been deprecated for some time now. sql 2012 is the last version that supports it. Not sure what you mean about saving a connection somewhere for rainy days but I understand about having 2 connection strings but they would be right next to each other in the config file.

Comment: @SeanLange I did not know about that. Thanks. But is there a solution for my problem for now?

Answer (score 4):

Pedram, sure you can. Go ahead and use `GetOleDbSchemaTable()` to get the details.

This is the way you proceed,

```
DataSet output = new DataSet();
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
{
    conn.Open();

    DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
        OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    // e.g. Rows in SchemaTable are Sheets in Xlsx file.
    foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        //... 
        string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        var select = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(select, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataTable outputTable = new DataTable(sheet);
        output.Tables.Add(outputTable);
        new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(outputTable);
    }
}
```

Later on when you got your `DataSet` you can get your `DataTable`s out of it using `myDataSet.Tables`, however they come in a `DataTableCollection` type which only support `Foreach` and not the `IEnumerable()` then you could do LINQ queries on it without the need for iteration. .NET developers haven't decided to implement this due to multiple reasons you can read extensively over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16805974/1316651).

However there is a very easy workaround and that's *Casting* it. So if you don't want to iterate over the collection and cherry pick the entries you want go ahead and use the following syntax in ***Method Syntax***:

```
var foo = dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Where(
            t => t.TableName == "The Table I want");
```

or in the ***Query syntax LINQ*** form as,

```
var bar = from DataTable t in dataSet.Tables
            where t.TableName == "The table I want" 
            select t;
```

Hope I understood you right though. I spent a fair bit of time figuring this out myself since I was curious.

**Update**

### Bulk Copy

If you want to copy your whole table over `OleDbConnection` to implement something like `SqlBulkCopy` does in `SqlConnection` you'll be looking to use `IRowsetFastLoad`. You didn't mention if you're using Ado.Net or just the pure OleDb. If it's the first option and you're using C# unfortunately `IRowsetFastLoad` is not implemented in this platform and only on C++. In this situation you are looking at iterating and grinding your teeth.

On the other hand if `SqlBulkCopy` is an option, I am pretty sure you're already all over it. If not, have a quick look at the following article. It clears lots of things up.

[Using SqlBulkCopy to efficiently copy table from Access to SQL Server](http://www.mywebdeveloperblog.com/development/using-sqlbulkcopy-to-efficiently-copy-table-from-access-to-sql-server)

I had a quick Googling and came across solutions such as using `adapter.Update()`, however I haven't used it this way before and won't be able to comment on it without testing.

[DbDataAdapter.Update Method (DataTable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Probably it worth having a look. Sorry, for the half way answer though. I had to go through your comments to fully understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hey Mehrad! The code snippet you provided looks very elegant. However, I already the source `DataTable` and the name of the destination table. What I would like to do is to INSERT all the rows in `DataTable` into the destination table. Do you think there is somewhere in your code in which you have provided the answer that I overlooked?

Comment: I think a solution like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075159/how-to-insert-a-data-table-into-sql-server-database-table will somehow do that job. Don't you think?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about that. Should do some tests.

Comment: I'd say the suggested link is also an SQL solution which could use the `SqlBulkCopy` instead if you went that way. I also updated my answer. Please have a look and let us know how you're doing.

Comment: But `SqlBulkCopy` works only with an `SqlConnection` and not an `OleDbConnection`.

Comment: I am aware of that, and was talking about the suggestion two comments above on another SO question which was suggesting a SQL based answer for a similar question.